# How to allow anonymous post comment so it will be saved in db when they login again?

Tags: php, session, cookies, comments

I want to allow anonymous users to post comments on my posts, so when they login again, we will save that comments to the database.

For example a user has uid = 1,but he is anonymous now, he can post comment to postid = 1. This comment will be stored somewhere (may be session), then when uid = 1 logs in, a record will be pushed to "comments" table in database.

Like this:

```
uid = 1
postid= 1
text = "some text here"
```

Can I use session, cookie or something to do this?

Comment: Yes. Call `session_start();` and then write something to the session (`$_SESSION['comment'] = $comment;`). If/when a user signs in, you can retrieve this comment and write it to the comments table, against their user ID. As @RUJordan says though, if your session expires (e.g. a user is only using session cookies, and they close their browser) then a comment will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do that, but the session will expire, and if cookies don't expire the client could manually erase them. So while you can check if the session and or cookie exist, you ultimately can't secure those values consistently without a login.

However, with some if statements to see if they are set, it is possible as long as again, the session hasn't expired nor the cookie.